# Page reloading in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, uitableview

**Summary of the issue:**
When I am loading some data into my iPhone application from a webservice, it populates the tableview two times with double number of records. I found that Viewdidload method is called two times causing this issue.

**Scenario**

From the first view I parse the webservice and collect the data into an array object.
This array object is being used by the second view to populate the tableview.

I am wondering what is behind reloading of the page causing the tableview has double number of records. Hope somebody can give me a hint.

Comment: are you using a mutable array or dictionary? if so, be sure to clear it before loading new values. this doesn't solve your problem, since it's not a good thing that `viewDidLoad` is called two times.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What I found the issue was the way adding the view. i replaced [self.view addSubview:trlist.view] with  [self presentModelViewController:trlist animated:NO]; and now it loads only one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips. What I found the issue was the way adding the view. i replaced [self.view addSubview:trlist.view] with [self presentModelViewController:trlist animated:NO]; and now it loads only one time.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider calling `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in your app delegate, as this is only called during launch.